# Sending email using xampp localhost

Tags: php, email, smtp, xampp

Please help me send email using php, I searched trough google and found out that I need to reconfigure/edit my php.ini and change SMTP value and smtp_port,

I dont know what exactly what will I put on those lines.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How should we know?  We don't know your ISP's SMTP server, and what ports will work for your network configuration.

Answer (score -1):

It would be a lot easier to use a phpmailer script like [this](http://deepakssn.blogspot.com/2006/06/gmail-php-send-email-using-php-with.html), but you can also do it without that by setting: smtp_ssl = ssl and configure the sendmail.ini so that it connects with your @gmail.com account credentials, or it will not be able to connect.