# How to send email from localhost to (gmail,yahoo etc.)

Tags: php

i am on windows environment (WAMP) want to check one of my application built in php which sends mails on localhost .please help how can i send email from localhost

Comment: Set up SMTP for your ISP's SMTP server in the `php.ini` configuration.

Comment: You'll need to connect to a mail server. If you have a Gmail account you could use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email using xampp localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344580/sending-email-using-xampp-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

I already have such a system running on my local machine.
If my server is ever online , you can check it out [here](http://enkrypt.dyndns-web.com/SMTP%20sendmail/)

I followed [this guide](http://www.projectpier.org/node/817) to help me through.
Make sure you do everything there except using projectpier , you dont need it. You'll be using Php to send mail.

Sample Php Code:

```
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header)) {
        echo "Mail successfully sent with given data"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        echo "Mail sending failed! Please make sure all data is correct and you are connected to the internet";
    }
```

Make sure you set up all the variables correctly